# Get Marker (org.osmdroid.bonuspack.overlays) from mMapView.getOverlays()

Tags: android, dictionary, android-mapview, osmdroid

I'm using OSMDroid.
I put my overlays marker in map view with

```
Marker startMarker = new Marker(mMapView);
startMarker.setPosition(VBA.getPosition());
startMarker.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_location_big));
startMarker.setTitle(VBA.getHotelName());
etc...

...
mMapView.getOverlays().add(startMarker);
```

Now i have to get all markers (for example thanks a foreach) to add a listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mMapView MapView.getOverlays()` returns a List of `Overlay`. Easy to scan.

Then to check if an overlay is a Marker:

```
if (overlay instanceof Marker) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks.. first i used Marker m = (Marker) o; but in the list there were some overlay not-Marker and this error appear: "cannot cast ...."